# Webpack builds react app with possibility to load vendor libs from node_modules on runtime

Tags: reactjs, webpack

We have a lot of React applications in our portal, there area lot of cases that there a a lot of them on same page but because of the size of those bundles the load time is very slow.

All application are using the classic combo react, redux, ramda...

So there is a lot of duplicity in each bundle, I am looking for a way to have those shared resources aside and cached by browser.

Is there a way to setup webpack build to dynamically load those common libraries from some url instead of bundling hem to the final bundle?

I use webpack 4, I have already tried SplitChunksPlugin, that is generating vendor chunk fine but it looks like that generated vendor chunk can be used just for one particular app

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

After the research I find out that there is a dll plugin that is doing exactly what I wanted: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/